# Is Haar Cascade the only available technique for image recognition in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I know that there are many detection techniques in OpenCV, such as SURF, STAR, ORB etc...but those techniques are for feature detection of new video feed, not for dealing with specific instances of objects that require prior learning. OpenCV's documentation isn't quite as easy to flip through and I've yet been able to find anything besides Haar, which I know deals best with face recognition.

So are there any other techniques besides Haar? The Haar technique dates back to research 10 years ago, so ideally I hope that there have been some more advances since then that have been implemented in OpenCV.

Comment: I'm also trying to develop something very similar. Would like to know how far you got.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are looking for OpenCV machine learning type algorithms, check out this [link](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/ml/doc/ml.html).

For a state of the art on-the-fly object detection algorithm, have a look at OpenTLD. It uses bounding boxes and random forests to learn about an object over time. Check out the demo video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1GhNXHCQGsM).

Also check out the matching_to_many_images.cpp sample from OpenCV. It uses feature descriptors to match objects much like Google Goggles works. A related example to this is the bagofwords_classification.cpp sample. It may be what you are looking for in this case. It uses feature detectors (SURF, SIFT, etc...) to detect objects and then classify them by comparing the relative positions of the features to a learned database of features. Have a look also at this [tutorial](http://people.csail.mit.edu/torralba/shortCourseRLOC/index.html) from MIT.

The latentsvmdetect.cpp may also be a good starting point for you.

Hope that helps!

Comment: openTLD looks awesome but it sadly only deals with one object at a time

Comment: What kind of objects are you trying to detect? Like if you are trying to detect people, you might look at the opencv peopledetect sample. It uses [HoG descriptors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients_(HOG)) and SVM (I believe) to train.

Comment: I'm trying to detect all objects, including people. Ideally in my implementation I want the software to recognize thousands of objects of different class and instances. I've been pretty stuck on finding the best algorithm for this. Is Haar the only thing I can use in OpenCV?

Comment: In order to classify all objects in a scene, you need to have trained your software as to what those objects are before hand. The data collection requirements on that task will be a bit steep :) It will be necessary to collect images of every object you want to classify (this is going to take most of your time). You'll need to use some kind of classifier (e.g., Haar Cascades, SVM, HoG, Boosted trees, etc...) to learn about a patch of pixels that you segment. The segmentation could involve edge detection or maybe background subtraction, or even manual segmentation.

Comment: which kind of classifier would work most efficiently? I'm currently constrained to a consumer class laptop. Are all these classifier unable to achieve on-the-fly object detection like openTLD? I want to achieve something similar to this, but without the kinect:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fQ59dXOo63o

Comment: essentially I want to be able to "hand train" the software, an object at a time. I don't need to get thousands of templates and train everything at once. Essentially, with enough hand training, the software should be able to recognize many things

Comment: After watching the video, there are several things to keep in mind. It appears he is using the Kinect to do range gating, which makes the object segmentation extremely easy. You could do something like background subtraction from a learned background (see the bgfg_segm.cpp sample) to get a binarized object mask. He is also keeping the objects at a fairly fixed scale and rotation; I doubt that the single training image is robust enough to pick the object out at an arbitrary pose. I have had good luck with SVM for classification, but Haar is used a lot for it's speed.

Comment: I'm looking into opentld a bit more now and it really seems like the ideal solution. However I still don't quite understand how it works. If I train 2 objects in it, and it sees both in the video, how would it know which object to track? Also, is it possible to name the objects that it detects? So when it tracks a car, my code would know that its a "car".